# Why was this character murdered?

Tags: plot-explanation, how-to-get-away-with-murder

I am a bit confused about *How to Get Away with Murder*, specifically the reason why

> Jorge Castillo ordered a hit on his daughter's boyfriend, Wes

We know that Castillos were offering Wes money to break up with their daughter, Laurel — something that Wes has refused. We know that Wes was planning to talk to the police, but if I remember correctly, he was going to admit to killing Sam (and probably incriminating Annalise). But that wouldn't most likely affect any of the Castillos (or at best Laurel could have problems for helping to dispose of the body).

So why was he killed?

Answer (score 1):

As was revealed in Season 4, *I believe*, that Castillo's were behind Wes's murder. Later we find out that it was his Laurel's father Jorge, who ordered the kill to prevent Wes's confession against/for Sam & Rebecca's murder. This was shown, as he refuses to sign deal and calls Annalise *(which goes to Annalise's voicemail, and becomes a major proof to frame Wes as Rebecca & Sam's murderer)* before he dies.

However it was never revealed explicitly what was Wes's immunity/plea deal. And we can only assume that Jorje Castillo was afraid of any bad publicity as his big project, Antares, was nearing a launch. The thought of having Laurel's name attached to any murder investigation would somehow affect his business negatively made him kill Wes.